# Add keyboard shortcut

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I want to make little app for my home.
It should detect keyboard shortcut (for example: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) and send now selected text to my app (like automator service).

How can I do it? May be you can give tutorial link to me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wanting an `Automator Action`.
In Xcode create an `Application Plug-in` `Automator Action` and post a notification to the `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`

```
- (id)runWithInput:(id)input fromAction:(AMAction *)anAction error:(NSDictionary **)errorInfo
{
    NSDistributedNotificationCenter *dc = [NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [dc postNotificationName:@"aName" object:@"anObject"
                    userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:input
                                                         forKey:@"aKey"]];
    return input;
}
```

You will need to implement an observer in your app

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(aSelector:) name:@"aName" object:nil];
```

If you include the Automator Action bundle in your app `${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/Contents/Library/Automator/`
Automator should be able to find it.